# Implement Captcha in android app code

Tags: java, android

I have to implement Captcha in my android app code, but have many errors in java classes ...

I worked this example:

https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha

**The field Captcha.height is not visible** in all this line:

```
this.height
```

**The method TextCaptcha(int, int, int, TextCaptcha.TextOptions) is undefined for the type TextCaptcha** in:

```
public TextCaptcha(int wordLength, TextOptions opt){
    TextCaptcha(0, 0, wordLength, opt);
}
```

**The field Captcha.width is not visible** in:

```
im.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(c.width *2, c.height *2));
```

**The constructor MathCaptcha(int, int, MathCaptcha.MathOptions) is undefined** in:

```
Captcha c = new MathCaptcha(300, 100, MathOptions.PLUS_MINUS_MULTIPLY);
```

Please can anyone help me out here or specify a script that really works ?

Comment: "I have to implement Captcha in my android app code" -- why? CAPTCHAs are for Web sites, to help prevent automated attacks.

Comment: Is not possible implement Captcha in android? Android app is immune to automated attacks ?

Comment: "Android app is immune to automated attacks ?" -- I am not aware of any attack vectors whereby somebody can simulate input on an Android GUI over a network. If you are aware of some, please provide links.

Comment: @Hamamelis I am also not aware, I don't think there is way to do so in Android. Captcha is required on your web sites where any other user can run bot to do like 1 Lacs + registration like activity in a second. To solve this problem you use Captcha there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Hamamelis you should do the following things when you import the project to your eclipse, change the following code in respective classes

```
this.setHeight(height);
```

in Mathcaptcha class, then

```
(c.getWidth() *2, c.getHeight() *2)
```

in CaptchatestActivity and last thing you have to do is change method name from

```
TextCaptcha(0, 0, wordLength, opt);
```

to

```
TextCaptch(0, 0, wordLength, opt);
```

in TextCapctha class and make return type of that method to void.